# How to chose the right language to build a git server web application like github?

Tags: git

I wish to create a git server for which I wish developers in my team to access their git repos through HTTP/git protocol by a web application. I want to develop this solution fairly in a short amount of time and i have to depend on the existing tools to do this. I am having a dilemma of choosing java/python/ruby(rails) for this purpose. Gitosis is in python, so Can I write my app in java and use gitosis to access the details of a git repo. Or should I use just python compulsarily to access git through gitosis ? Is there any other good and complete tool like gitosis for java ? I hope All these questions will lead me to choose the language in which I must implement the server code of the web application.

I am not an experience web developer so please guide me on this. Which is the right language for implementing the server code for this web application ?

Comment: Why do you need to develop your own instead of using an existing server?

Comment: I have been doing just textbased and database based web apps till now, and now i want my team to use OUR git server instead of outsourcing that dept to github like sites.. since Im fairly new to setting up git servers, I am asking help here ..

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand what you want to do.  Could you elaborate?

Do you want to create git hosting site / git forge like [GitHub](http://github.com), but you want to host it and do not want to shell money for [GitHub:FI](http://fi.github.com)?  If it is true, then you can use one of existing open source git hosting software (see [InterfacesFrontendsAndTools](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools) page on Git wiki):

- [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/gitorious) (in Ruby, like GitHub)
- [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net) (in PHP)
- [Girocco](http://repo.or.cz/w/girocco.git) (powers repo.or.cz, in Perl and bash)

Gitosis (or similar Gitolite tool) are about access control to Git repositories via git, and are managed from a command line, not from web.

If you want to create git forge or web interface for git repository management, take a look at [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/), which is web based code review and project management for Git based projects, written in Java and using **JGit** (implementation of Git in Java) and Mina SSH daemon.  It was described in [Gerrit: Google-style code review meets git](http://lwn.net/Articles/359489/) at LWN.net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gitorious for this purpose:

http://www.gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/UbuntuInstallation

It's a headache to get set up and working but worth the effort. Definitely beats developing your own solution.